# How to open a csv in powershell and duplicate one of the columns, so I now have 2 columns with the same data, but different names?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv that I import using the import-csv command, like the below:

```
emailAddress,   event,  tokenDate,  Yadda1, Yadda2
aaaa@bbb.com,   A1234,  23/03/2020, 98765,  54321
bbbb@ccc.com,   B2345,  23/03/2020, 87654,  32109
cccc@ddd.com,   C3456,  23/03/2020, 76543,  21098
```

I have code that imports the csv, excluding some columns I do not want (yadda1, yadda2) and it then renames the headers it imports.

After importing and renaming I have code that changes the status_date columns data to unixtime format and this works perfectly.

What I need to do now is to add a NEW column called "status_date2", which contains exactly the same data as status_date for each row, so if status_date on row 50 contains the unixtime value of 1584370028 then the new status_date2 of row 50 needs to also now hold the value 1584370028.

I have tried to do something like this, which I thought would simply take the value of status_date, but the status_date2 column is empty all the way down - PLEASE HELP!!!

```
@{Name='status_date2';Expression={$_."status_date"}}
```

The code looks like this:

```
Import-Csv "c:\temp\myCSV.csv" |
Select * -ExcludeProperty "emailAddress", "event", "tokenDate" |

# Rename the column headers, for exmaple: rename from emailAddress to email_address


select -Property @{label="email_address";expression={$($_."emailAddress")}}, 
@{label="status";expression={$($_."event")}},
@{label="status_date";expression={$($_."tokenDate")}},

#Replace the date column data with unixtime format
% {$_.status_date = (Get-Date($_.status_date) -UFormat %s); $_} |

# Add a new column with current date/time is unixtime format for the CRM
@{Name='status_date2';Expression={Get-Date -UFormat %s}} |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make the same calculation twice (for translation-only fields you can simply specify the name as the `Expression` value):

```
Import-Csv "c:\temp\myCSV.csv" |Select -Property @{Label="email_address";Expression="emailAddress"}, 
@{Label="status";Expression="event"},
@{Label="status_date";expression={Get-Date $_."tokenDate" -UFormat %s}},
@{Label="status_date2";expression={Get-Date $_."tokenDate" -UFormat %s}}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Worked a treat!!